# Application fails to start due to Argument exception

Tags: java, openjpa

```
    public interface AppUserLoginHistoryRepository
        extends JpaRepository<AppUserLoginHistory, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<AppUserLoginHistory> {

    @Query("UPDATE AppUserLoginHistory logdet"
       + " JOIN FETCH (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT loginSystemDate) AS loginDate FROM AppUserLoginHistory WHERE tlr = :username) logdet2"
       + " ON logdet.loginSystemDate = logdet2.loginDate SET logdet.logoutComputerDate = :logoutDate, logdet.forcedLogout = :isForcedLogout")
    @Modifying
    void updateAppUserLogout(@Param("logoutDate") Date logoutDate, @Param("isForcedLogout") boolean isForcedLogout, @Param("username") String username);

}
```

Am getting below error from the above snippets

*Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "JOIN" at character 35, but expected: ["SET"]." while parsing JPQL "UPDATE AppUserLoginHistory logdet JOIN FETCH (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT loginSystemDate) AS loginDate FROM AppUserLoginHistory WHERE tlr = :username) logdet2 ON logdet.loginSystemDate = logdet2.loginDate SET logdet.logoutComputerDate = :logoutDate, logdet.forcedLogout = :isForcedLogout". See nested stack trace for original parse error.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:54)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:165)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:718)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:692)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:728)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:627)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1149)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor219.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy344.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "JOIN" at character 35, but expected: ["SET"].
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.generateParseException(JPQL.java:13188)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.jj_consume_token(JPQL.java:13064)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.set_clause(JPQL.java:735)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.update_clause(JPQL.java:731)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.update_statement(JPQL.java:148)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQL.parseQuery(JPQL.java:66)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.parse(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:2439)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:2426)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)
    ... 110 common frames omitted*

Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT

From SQL I tried the query with WHERE clause as below.

```sql
UPDATE m_appuser_logdetails
   SET logout_computer_date = '2021-02-20 13:12:09'
 WHERE login_computer_date = (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT login_computer_date)
                                FROM m_appuser_logdetails)
   AND user_id=1 LIMIT 1
```

but I get error

> SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'm_appuser_logdetails' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Create a string variable and get there the result of the SQL, copy it and paste it in you DBMS. to me, looks like a error in the sql string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason for the `JOIN FETCH` part.
Is there something preventing you from using the following?

```
UPDATE AppUserLoginHistory logdet
SET logdet.logoutComputerDate = :logoutDate
   ,logdet.forcedLogout = :isForcedLogout
```

Comment: A user can login in several times without user initiated logout from the system am trying to build. So the field **loginSystemDate** can as well be as many times as a user has logged in. So from the list of the several rows for a particular user i would like to update the latest login row and ignore the rest for that user. Hope i have explain the concept for this

Comment: @IppezRobert I suggest adding a WHERE clause to your UPDATE.

Comment: from sql i tried the query with WHERE clause as below `UPDATE m_appuser_logdetails SET logout_computer_date = '2021-02-20 13:12:09'
WHERE login_computer_date = (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT login_computer_date) FROM m_appuser_logdetails) 
AND user_id=1 LIMIT 1` but i get error _SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'm_appuser_logdetails' for update in FROM clauseuery_

Comment: Working modified SQL Query is `UPDATE m_appuser_logdetails SET logout_computer_date = '2020-02-21 18:00:28' 
WHERE login_computer_date IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT login_computer_date) 
FROM m_appuser_logdetails WHERE user_id=1) as t)`

Comment: @IppezRobert I suggest you [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)